# power point: how to change transparency of entire grouped object?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In a power point presentation I have an object that is a grouped cluster of a bunch of stuff, mostly text and a couple of images. I want to use it on my title slide, but set the transparency high so it appears more as a subtle background feature. I can't find a way to do this I can only find ways to change transparency of individual sub-items in the object, but this would be inefficient and time-consuming.

One workaround would be to overlay a rectangle over the object group, and set the transparency of the rectangle as a kind of mask, but is there a more direct way?>

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly elegant, but I saved the group as a picture and imported it. Then I was able to control the opacity of the resulting image. This is not ideal either, but may be easier than a transparent mask if you don't anticipate needing to ungroup and play with it elsewhere in the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Also not perfect, but if you add a transparency animation to the group, it works. That proves it is possible to change the transparency of all different items in a group. Hopefully Microsoft will add that functionality to group formatting.

Not perfect because the animation starts after the slide, even if configured to start with previous, with zero delay.